# Removing specific Position from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to remove Pitchers('P') from the dictionary of potential players.
I have tried setting

`team: [player for player in players_dict.keys() if player.team == team and player.positions != 'P']`

but it still creates a dictionary with the players in it.

```
class TeamStacksRule(OptimizerRule):
    def apply(self, solver, players_dict):
        stacks = self.optimizer.team_stacks
        players_by_teams = {
            team: [player for player in players_dict.keys() if player.team == team]
            for team in self.optimizer.available_teams
        }

        stacks_dict = {}
        for i, stack in enumerate(sorted(stacks, reverse=True), start=1):
            stacks_dict[stack] = i

        for stack, total in stacks_dict.items():
            combinations_variables = []

            for team, players in players_by_teams.items():
                solver_variable = solver.add_variable('teams_stack_%d_%s' % (stack, team))
                combinations_variables.append(solver_variable)
                variables = [players_dict[player] for player in players]
                solver.add_constraint(variables, None, SolverSign.GTE,
                                      stack * solver_variable)
            solver.add_constraint(combinations_variables, None, SolverSign.GTE, total)
```

Comment: Please give [mcve] specifying input to your program and what do you expect as output for that input. *"but it still creates a dictionary..."* - That code creates a list as output, not dictionary any way.

Comment: I notice that the attribute is called `positions`, not `position`. Is it possible for a player to have more than one position? If so, it's likely that `positions` is a list and not a string. That would mean that `player.positions != 'P'` is always True, because a list never equals a string. What happens if you do `'P' not in player.positions` instead?

Comment: @Kevin thank you that worked